# TCPDF weird issue in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, formatting, pdf-generation, tcpdf, html-to-pdf

I am having a formatting issue with PDF generation with TCPDF in CakePHP.

It doesn't show the exact table & div structure as there in HTML.

Does anyone know the solution for it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my solution by changing my code to clean html into the tcpdf format means by using `cell` and `multicell` function of tcpdf.

Refrence : http://www.onemoretake.com/2009/03/09/tcpdf-variable-height-table-rows-with-multicell/

Answer (score 0):

Code that i m sending u is for creating xls file and u just need to change some header prameter in it.

Just put this code in the head of your html file and it will force u to download automatically.But change the header according to pdf file

Comment: question is about tcpdf and your answer relates to xls which is ir relavant